# Opentext ECM - List all Folders and Files with C# GUI

Tags: c#, opentext, ecm

I want to develop a tool for my company using C# and .net to access our opentext ECM Documents. I need to be able to search in opentext ECM "Folders" for Word Documents, search inside old document links and update.

I see opentext ECM in the Windows Explorer, but cant access with C# with SpecialFolders Biblio.

Does anyone know how I can access with C# Net to opentext ECM - my tool must see the Folders, must see the files and open the files. I need a little help for my start.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the soap API for that. It offers all the functions you want. You need to license the SDK to have access to the API and the related documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the REST API to retrieve the folders and documents. REST APIs offered most of the document management features like list folders and documents, upload download documents, reserve and unreserve the documents etc. Please note that the REST APIs are available from v16.